Why this construction proves every infinite cardinal is limit ordinal
Here's the proof: Infinite cardinal is limit ordinal. Let $\alpha$ be an infinite ordinal. Then, it must be a limit ordinal.
Proof: Suppose otherwise that $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal. That is, there exists $\beta$ such that $\alpha = \beta + 1$. In the linked post, they construct the map
$$f: \beta + 1 \rightarrow \beta$$
$$f(\beta) = 0;\quad f(x) = x + 1 \text{ if } x < \omega;\quad f(x) = x \text{ if } x \text{ infinite}$$
This clearly fails if $\beta$ is any ordinal.
How do you make sure that $x + 1$ is in $\beta$ since the constructed map is from $\beta + 1$ to $\beta$? Everything understood except that part.

Please, include the context in the post. The users in the forum shouldn't have to follow any link to understand your question. Links should be used only for complementary information.

@jjagmath Sorry.

The obvious observation is that: $\omega$ is the least infinite ordinal. Thus,
$$x + 1 < \omega \leq \beta$$
$\beta$ must be infinite since otherwise $\beta + 1$ is finite and hence $\alpha$ cannot be a infinite cardinal

Why the downvote? This answer might be useful if someone fail to notice this small detail. It might be helpful to future visitors. Also, how is this even wrong?

May be an example helps. Take $\beta = \omega + 4 = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots,\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3\}$.
The function been defined is the following:
$f:\omega + 5\to\omega + 4$
that is
$f:\{0,1,2,3,\ldots,\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3,\omega+4\} \to \{0,1,2,3,\ldots,\omega,\omega+1,\omega+2,\omega+3\}$
defined by
\begin{align}
f(\omega)&=\omega\\
f(\omega+1)&=\omega+1\\
f(\omega+2)&=\omega+2\\
f(\omega+3)&=\omega+3\\
f(\omega + 4)&=0\\
f(0)&=1\\
f(1)&=2\\
f(2)&=3\\
f(3)&=4\\
\vdots\\
\end{align}
which is clearly a bijection.
